# Error with bind_param() when updating a record in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Why am I getting the error below? The code works, and updates the database like it should It just gives me this error. I'm pretty new to PHP so please forgive me ignorance.

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of
>   variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

here are my code:

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.inc.php');
    $conn = dbConnect('write');
    // prepare SQL statement 
    $sql = "UPDATE reimbursements 
                SET presidentstatus='$p_submit',
                    treasurerstatus='$t_submit', 
                    checknumber='$check_submit', 
                    paid='$paid_submit' 
            WHERE id='$id'";
    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // bind parameters and insert the details into the database
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $p_submit, $t_submit, $check_submit, $paid_submit);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        $success = "Information has been updated.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem with the database.';
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

### You forgot to bind the **`$id`** as a parameter.

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $p_submit, $t_submit, $check_submit, $paid_submit, $id);
                       ^------ (assuming id is an integer thus `i`)           ^^^------- (added)
```

Comment: I changed the code to bind the $id, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: What is the datatype of your id on your table ?

Comment: the datatype is INT. I "commented out" $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $p_submit, $t_submit, $check_submit, $paid_submit); and now it works, and I don't get any errors. do I need to bind the parameters?